# How to extract text of paragraph from html using Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JavaApplication14 {


public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146").get();  
         String html= "<html><head></head>" + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc."
                 + "</p></body></html>"; 
  Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
  for(Element p : paragraphs)
    System.out.println(p.text());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication14.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

can anyone help me with jsoup code how can i parse just portion including paragraph so that just print

```
Hello ,World!
Nothing is impossible
```

Comment: i just tried  this                                  imporjava.io.IOException;
   import org.jsoup.*;
   import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    public class JavaApplication10 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
 


     Document document =    Jsoup.connect("https://tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146").get();
String html;
        html = "<html><head></head>"
   + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    // ...
}



    }

Comment: I note that you're not using `document`... and you're not doing anything with `doc` after you create it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this small bit of html you just need to do

```
String html= "<html><head></head>" + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc."+
                    +"</p></body></html>"; 
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); 
Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
for(Element p : paragraphs)
  System.out.println(p.text());
```

As I see your link contains pretty much the same html you could then also replace the definition of `doc` with

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146").get();
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the full code that compiles and runs fine for me.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class JavaApplication14 {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
      String url = "https://tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146";
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
      Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
      for(Element p : paragraphs)
        System.out.println(p.text());
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication14.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put large chunks of text in a comment like that - it's unreadable. When you say still no luck, what actually happens?

Comment: ok i am new to stack overflow ,i dont know how to edit a comment.

Comment: no luck means it is showingException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146
 at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:55)

Comment: Ah yes you need `Jsoup.connect("https://tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146").get();` - the url needs the protocol.

Comment: It would be best if you updated your original post with it so that this thread contained a record of what was done so that other people could learn from it. You can add this code by clicking edit below your post.

Comment: Replace `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146").get(); ` with `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tanmoy_mahathir.makes.org/thimble/146").get();`

Comment: I tried with Https:// before but it dont works then i discarded that and still it dont work.

Comment: It works for me fine - I've added the code that compiles and runs for me in my answer.

Comment: Yeah your code is running fine.what was the problem of mine.Did i tried using html as string,is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You may start by trying this....

```
String url = "url of the html page";
Document page = Jsoup.parse(url);

Elements elements = page.select("div[class=class_name] p");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Element firstPara = d.select("div.post-content p").first() ;2
2. System.out.println(firstPara);

you can select tag with it's class and then can go more specific like getting first paragraph