# Why am I always getting a IOException?

Tags: java, android, exception, jsoup, ioexception

Please have a look at the following code

**TT.Java**

```
public class TT extends Activity{

private EditText textField;

    private boolean isSpeaking = false;

    private AudioManager audioManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_talk);


        textField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textField);
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(getIntent().getAction())) 
    {
        String text = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        Document doc;

         try {
              doc = Jsoup.connect("http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation").get();
              Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
              for(Element p : paragraphs)
              {
                //System.out.println(p.text());
                textField.setText(p.text());
              }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                textField.setText(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                Toast.makeText(this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } 


    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.talk, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

This class can be called when you click the "Share-Via" button of your android web browser, and select this program. The purpose of this class is to extract text(only text) from the shared webpage (any page) and display it in this `EditText`. Unfortunately, This did not give me any output. Instead it generates a *`IOException`* and prints the URL.

The `IOException` I get I have never seen before. The exception I get is

```
doc.opencv.org
```

The `JSoup` part is extracted from the selected answer of this thread - [How to extract text of paragraph from html using Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161243/how-to-extract-text-of-paragraph-from-html-using-jsoup). In that case, the SO member says it is working!

Following is how I added this class to the `Share-Via`

**AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.xxx.xxx.TT"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Below is the complete stacktrace

```
10-09 13:45:18.244: I/TextToSpeech.java(1325): initTts() successfully bound to service
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325): IOException in share
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325): java.net.UnknownHostException: docs.opencv.org
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:322)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at com.xxx.xxx.TT.onCreate(Talk.java:71)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-09 13:45:18.464: E/IOException_Share(1325):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have used `JSoup` library here but I have no experience in it. Why am I continuously getting the `IOException`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to practice on tutorials and learn DOM and html basics.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: @DanielB: How to get the stacktrace in android? I tried toasting it but didn't work properly

Comment: That's not an exception, that's just a hostname. Please post the entire exception and stack trace.

Comment: @EJP: That is done. Please have a look

Comment: Do you have this in manifest.xml? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> Ooops. To late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I was missing the Internet permission in Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```